# What is the significance of dead meat?

Tags: analysis, repulsion

In [Repulsion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repulsion_(film)), This dead meat appeared so many times.

[image]

What is the significance of this dead meat ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply supposed to evoke a response from the viewer.  It's supposed to repulse you, so you feel the way Carol does about all the world around her, similar to the way the hands coming out of the wall are supposed to make you feel her claustrophobia.  It also represents (to me) the way Carol feels when objectified by the men in the movie; like a piece of meat.